# Issues with pydatatable frame output in google colab

Tags: python, py-datatable

I'm doing data wrangling on a dataset using **pydatatable** in google colab notebooks, on executing code chunks its displaying two different output formats of a frame, where as the same dataframe with pandas displays a single output, i'm attaching hera a screenshot of it for reference. [image]

Could you please let me know any options should be configured in **dt displays** to have a correct output format?. or something is wrong in google colab notebooks?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been clarified to me by pydatatable team, and i would have to contact google colab team for this issue. and for now i'm not going to use this in Colab notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

it should be fixed by google colab team.

Answer (score 0):

Since the version 1.0.0 it is displaying a single output.

[image]